# Next.js:FetchError: invalid json response body Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) to simply make a request and then pass that data from it to a component:

But I'm getting this error:

> FetchError: invalid json response body at
> https://www.ajmadison.com/product3.0/packages.index.json.php?sku=RF28R7351SR
> reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
import AppliancePackage from '../components/AppliancePackage.jsx';

function HomePage({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      <AppliancePackage appliances={data} />
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;

// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It won't be called on client-side, so you can even do
// direct database queries. See the "Technical details" section.

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get data.
  // You can use any data fetching library

  var res = await fetch(
    'https://www.ajmadison.com/product3.0/packages.index.json.php?sku=RF28R7351SR'
  );

   var json = await res.json();

   data = JSON.stringify(json);
   console.log('data ', data);

  return {
    props: {
      data: json,
    },
  };
}
```

I tried to Stringify it, but that didn't work! Also I am kind of confused by the comments:

> This function gets called at build time on server-side.
> It won't be called on client-side, so you can even do
> direct database queries. See the "Technical details" section.

And then as you can see there is a comment that states:

> Call an external API endpoint to get posts.

But have a whole section regarding API routes in their [docs](https://next-site-git-new-docs.zeit.now.sh/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Anyone can help me what is the matter?

**Update**

Alexey contributed some great insight, but like I said to him I can't find in the axios docs to change the user-agent!

Answer (score 3):

Alexey got me on the right track! Thanks my friend!

Wound up you have to do this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
  // You can use any data fetching library

  var res = await axios.get(
    'https://www.ajmadison.com/product3.0/packages.index.json.php?sku=RF28R7351SR',
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': '*',
      },
    }
  );
  var res = JSON.stringify(res.data);
  console.log('res ', res);

  // By returning { props: posts }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      data: res,
    },
  };
}
```

this being adding the headers:

```
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': '*',
  },
```

And `*` for any `User-Agent`

Answer (score 2):

I think the endpoint you're referring to is for some reason sensitive to "User-Agent".

When I tried fetching it with CURL like this, it returned some HTML response (which is not valid JSON ofcourse)

```
curl https://www.ajmadison.com/product3.0/packages.index.json.php?sku=RF28R7351SR
```

But this way it did work and returned JSON, just like if reached via browser:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: some browser" https://www.ajmadison.com/product3.0/packages.index.json.php?sku=RF28R7351SR
```

TLDR: try adding "user-agent" header to your request.

Comment: Thanks but I tried looking at the `axios` docs to add that—but couldn't find it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried like this?  https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2560#issuecomment-555778304

Answer (score 2):

For me it was `.json()` called for HTTP errors returning HTML in response body

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `res.status(200).json(data)` in the `api file`, use `res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(data))`. This will eliminate JSON error in the console. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think the data is not been fetch from the end that why.
i face same problems i restarted my system and network and it works perfectly back

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32716689)