# getServerSideProps error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using next.js and I want to fetch data from my data1.json file via getStaticProps(). The problem is that I get the error:

> FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/data/data1.json reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I have following code:

**trainings.js** (*projectfolder*/pages/trainings.js)

```
export default function Trainings({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>My trainings</h1>
    </main>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/data1.json');
  const data = await res.json();

  return { props: { data } };
}
```

**data1.json** (*projectfolder*/data/data1.json)

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jescie Duncan",
        "email": "nunc@protonmail.couk",
        "address": "Ap #666-9989 Nisi Avenue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Karen Bartlett",
        "email": "tellus.imperdiet@aol.couk",
        "address": "P.O. Box 787, 2857 Tincidunt Ave"
    },
    {
        "name": "Teegan Valdez",
        "email": "lacus.mauris.non@hotmail.edu",
        "address": "Ap #474-300 Nullam Avenue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Stuart Silva",
        "email": "nulla.donec.non@google.edu",
        "address": "336-2367 Eu Ave"
    }
]
```

Comment: Think this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960214/next-jsfetcherror-invalid-json-response-body-unexpected-token-in-json-at-pos

Comment: thank you RoboMop for your response, but it should be also possible without axio right? Now I've created a data1.js file within the api folder (as @Shiva suggested) and now I have at least access to the json file when I directly access it in the browser. But not via my trainings.js file :(

Comment: Fetching from `http://localhost:3000/data/data1.json` is not the right way to access your local data. There's also no need to create an API route for it as `getServerSideProps` runs on the server already. So you can simply import the JSON file with `import data from '<path-to>/data/data1.json'` at the top of the `trainings.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether `http://localhost:3000/data/data1.json` api is working or not. Because Nextjs support React components as default support in the pages folder not JSON. If you want serve as API you need to use NextJS api routes which you need to specifically put logic inside `api` folder.

in `api/data/data1.js` file

```
import data from '/path/to/json'
async function handler(req, res) {
  return res.status(200).json(data)
}

export default handler;
```

But a better approach is:
As you have JSON file, you directly import that data in `trainings.js` rather than calling an API.

```
import data from 'path/to/json';
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  return { props: { data } };
}
```

Comment: no i couldn't access http://localhost:3000/data/data1.json. Now I have created the data1.js in the api folder. And to this I have access via the URL and the json data is shown correctly. The Problem is i want to access the data1.js file via my trainings.js file. But if I do so now I get the error message `TypeError: (0 , _api_data1__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.handler) is not a function` I want to test how I could acess it via an API (in the future my data1.json should be stored on a different server), I know that this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with this error:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

There might be some hidden file/s included in your "data" folder. In my case it's `.DS_Store` file. So what I did is,

1. move this `"data" folder somewhere`
2. in your root directory, create a new folder named "data" (again)
3. now go back to your moved `"data" folder somewhere` and get all the JSON files by selecting it one-by-one, NOT doing the "Select All Files" because you might still pick the hidden files you are trying to get rid of
4. copy and paste these JSON files to your newly created "data" folder

This solved my problem every time it's happening. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do it but I am surviving by doing this multiple times.

Comment: If you have a folder that can only contain JSON files, and it has a rogue file in it, I wonder if I would create a script to list the non-JSON files. Files like `.DS_Store` from a Mac environment can safely be deleted.