# Type error: Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPaths<ParsedUrlQuery>'

Tags: typescript, next.js, es6-promise

Have the following errors

> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPaths'.
>
> > Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetStaticPathsResult>'.
> >
> > > Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPathsResult'.

I get an error at getStaticPaths in the following

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (ctx) => {  
  const slug = ctx.params?.study! as IParams;

  const studyReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/studies?where[slug][equals]=${slug}`);
  const studyData = await studyReq.json();


  return {
    props: {
      study: studyData.docs[0],
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const studyReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/studies?limit=100`);
  const studyData = await studyReq.json();

  return {
    paths: studyData.docs.map(({ slug }) => ({
      params: { study: slug },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

I'm quite new to typescript and next js. Everything works fine on local. But, the deployment fails. I went through some issues on github and here are a few that I've tried.

1. Adding an interface with slug as a string. Fails with incompatible type error with study. [Ref 1](https://wallis.dev/blog/nextjs-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-with-typescript), [Ref 2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16522)
2. Strigify json. Fails with Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'string'. [Ref 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960214/next-jsfetcherror-invalid-json-response-body-unexpected-token-in-json-at-pos)

Project can be found here - https://github.com/payloadcms/custom-website-series

Here's the entire file

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from 'react';
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths } from 'next';
import { Cell, Grid } from '@faceless-ui/css-grid';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from '../../components/Head';
import Template from '../../components/layout/Template';
import useStyles from '../../css/pages/study';
import { Type as FooterType } from '../../globals/Footer';
import { Type as SocialMediaType } from '../../globals/SocialMedia';
import { Type as StudyType } from '../../collections/Study';
import GridContainer from '../../components/layout/GridContainer';
import RenderBlocks from '../../components/RenderBlocks';
import Media from '../../components/Media';
import Gutter from '../../components/layout/Gutter';
import { AbsoluteNoise } from '../../components/Noise/AbsoluteNoise';


export type Props = {
  study: StudyType
  statusCode: number
  footer: FooterType
  socialMedia: SocialMediaType
}



const Study: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { footer, socialMedia, study } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Template
      className={classes.studies}
      footer={footer}
      socialMedia={socialMedia}
    >
      <Head
        title={study.meta?.title || study.title}
        description={study.meta?.description}
        keywords={study.meta?.keywords}
      />
      <GridContainer>
        <header className={classes.header}>
          <div className={classes.label}>
            <Link href="/studies">
              <a className={classes.label}>
                Study
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <h1 className={classes.title}>{study.title}</h1>
        </header>
      </GridContainer>
      <div className={classes.featuredMediaWrap}>
        <Gutter
          right
          className={classes.featuredMediaGutter}
        >
          <Media
            {...study.featuredMedia}
            preferredSize="feature"
            className={classes.featuredMedia}
          />
        </Gutter>
        {(study?.client || study?.location || study?.categories) && (
          <GridContainer>
            <Grid
              htmlElement="ul"
              className={classes.meta}
            >
              {study?.client && (
                <Cell
                  htmlElement="li"
                  cols={3}
                  start={2}
                >
                  <div className={classes.metaLabel}>
                    Client
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {study.client}
                  </div>
                </Cell>
              )}
              {study?.categories?.length > 0 && (
                <Cell
                  htmlElement="li"
                  cols={3}
                >
                  <div className={classes.metaLabel}>
                    Categories
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {study.categories.map((category, i) => (
                      <span key={i}>
                        {category.title}
                        {i !== study.categories.length - 1 && (
                          ', '
                        )}
                      </span>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Cell>
              )}
              {study?.location && (
                <Cell
                  htmlElement="li"
                  cols={3}
                  startM={2}
                >
                  <div className={classes.metaLabel}>
                    Location
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {study.location}
                  </div>
                </Cell>
              )}

              <AbsoluteNoise className={classes.backgroundNoise} />
            </Grid>
          </GridContainer>
        )}
      </div>
      <RenderBlocks layout={study.layout} />
    </Template>
  );
};

export default Study;


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (ctx) => {  

  const slug = ctx.params?.study;

  const studyReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/studies?where[slug][equals]=${slug}`);
  const studyData = await studyReq.json();


  return {
    props: {
      study: studyData.docs[0],
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const studyReq = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/studies?limit=100`);
  const studyData = await studyReq.json();



  return {
    paths: studyData.docs.map(({ slug }) => ({
      params: { study: slug },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```